# What is going wrong with my hasCycle() method using DFS?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, cycle

I am trying to make a simple `hasCycle()` method that detects cycle in a graph, but I am facing some problems in it.

The code I am using is:

```
public static boolean hasCycle(Graph g, Vertex prev, Vertex u, Set<Vertex> known) {
known.add(u);

for(Vertex temp : g.getNeighbours(u)){
  if(!known.contains(temp)){
    if(hasCycle(g,u,temp,known))
      return true;

    else if(temp != prev)  
      return true;
  }
}

return false;
}

public static boolean hasCycle(Graph g) {
Set<Vertex> known = new TreeSet<>();

for(Vertex u : g.getAllVertices()){
  known.add(u);
  return hasCycle(g,u,u,known); // is this correct, how do I overload this method
}

return false;
}
```

When I am testing it for an input like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph g = new Graph();
    Vertex v = new Vertex(0);
    Vertex w = new Vertex(1);

    g.addVertex(v);
    g.addVertex(w);
    g.addEdge(v, w);
    System.out.println(hasCycle(g)); // this is printing true
}
```

And

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph g = new Graph();
    Vertex v = new Vertex(0);

    g.addVertex(v);
    g.addEdge(v, v);
    System.out.println(hasCycle(g)); // this is printing false
}
```

I am not able to understand what's going wrong. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should really write than with pen and paper before starting to implement, also add a lot of comments if you trying to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move the else statement to the outer if... Also the function taking just the graph should not return on the first iteration...

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails cause:

---

function hasCycle(Graph g) is wrong, because:

- it return true/false based on all nodes reachable from first node
  (what if graph is disconnected?)

---

function hasCycle(Graph g, Vertex prev, Vertex u, Set known) is also wrong:

- You return true only if you find a neighbouring node to the current
  one that is not visited and not equal to previous node that doesn't
  make any sense for finding cycle.

---

Suggestion:

Refer to some tutorials like: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/ and try understanding how cycle finding algorithm work, then try implementing it

Answer (score 0):

This code will work. I haven't tested.

```
import java.util.*;

public class DetectCycle {
  public boolean dfs(Graph g, Vertex u, Set<Vertex> known) {
    known.add(u);
    for (Vertex v: g.getNeighbours(u)) {
      if (known.contains(v)) {
        return true;
      }
      return this.dfs(g, v, known);
    }
    return false;
  }

  public boolean hasCycle(Graph g) {
    Set<Vertex> known = new Set<Vertex>();
    for (Vertex v: g.getAllVertices()) {
      if (known.contains(v)) {
        continue;
      }
      known.add(v);
      if (this.dfs(g, v, new Set<Vertex>())) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph g = new Graph();
    Vertex v = new Vertex(0);
    Vertex w = new Vertex(1);

    g.addVertex(v);
    g.addVertex(w);
    g.addEdge(v, w);
    System.out.println(this.hasCycle(g));
  }
}
```

Please note that I am passing a newly initialized known set for each DFS call. Each DFS will have its own copy of visited vertices. If we encounter the  vertex twice in an individual DFS call, the graph is said to have a cycle.